# How can i put a countdown in front of an image?

Tags: android, image, countdown

I want put an image and IN FRONT a countdown(first appear Countdown and down of countdown will appear an image)

I have this code:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

This is the countdown, but when i put an image, countdown appear down of image, and i don´t see the countdown D:
Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Can you edit your question adding your `.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this using a *RelativeLayout* in your layout xml file.

First, set the ImageView, then align the TextView accordingly, using the **id**  of the ImageView. The result will be a ImageView with an overlayed TextView.

In the example below, the TextView is aligned to the left of the ImageView, using **layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
        android:text="My Countdown"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `android:layout_alignLeft`, `android:layout_alignTop`,     `android:layout_alignRight`, and `android:layout_alignBottom` to make the size of the TextView fit the ImageView

Comment: @Mariux
D:
Thanks but is not that i want, i want... this:
[http://imageshack.com/a/img10/6246/amx9.jpg]

Comment: @FabianMontossi link is broken.

Comment: @Mariux
 imageshack.com/a/img10/6246/amx9.jpg

Fuc*** S**t o.O

Comment: That's exactly what you get using the RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Mariux not really, i use it, and when i run the app i get the text in  bot when i have the image in top for example :|

Answer (score 0):

I think u'r Image is over the Textfiles. Take a Look on u'r xml

Comment: No because i dont have the Countdown in my layout, idk how to move it, because i dont see it xD

Comment: ok and why u don't set it on the xml? u can set it in the layout to invisible and if the countdown start u can set it to visible and if this is finish u can set it to gone